# Solving a tough system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

I have three equations and have to solve for $x, y, z$.

$$ l_1l_2 + m_1m_2 + n_1n_2 = 0 $$
$$ xl_1 + ym_1 + zn_1 = 0 $$
$$ xl_2 + ym_2 + zn_2 = 0 $$

After eliminating a variable (from the last two), I am left with an equation in two variables. I don't know how to proceed after that - by bringing in the first equation.

This is where I am stuck:
$$ y(m_1l_2 - m_2l_1) + z(n_1l_1 - n_2l_1) = 0 $$

I can do the same for other variables too, but that doesn't leave me anywhere - which is obvious since I am not using the first equation. So how to do this?

**EDIT**:
The original problem is to prove that:
$$x = m_1n_2 - m_2n_1$$
$$y = n_1l_2 - n_2l_1$$
$$z = l_1m_2 - l_2m_1$$

That can easily done by substituting this in both the equations and showing that it satisfies. But say this wasn't given, what should've been the approach in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** the three equations tell you that the various dot products of three vectors, one of which is $(x,y,z)$, is zero. What other vector can you think of that is orthogonal to two given vectors? There is a big fat hint in the form of the parentheses in the equation you derived.

Comment: Funny thing is that the (original) question is regarding vectors only - two are given to be mutually perpendicular, and we have to find the vector that's perpendicular to both.

Comment: I don't know how to proceed further. The first equation gives "homogeneous" terms (like $l_1l_2$ etc) and we need non-homogeneous terms.

Comment: You should realize that the solution is not unique! $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ is a solution, after all. If you have done some vector calculus, the presence $(m_1l_2-m_2l_1)$ should ring a bell. But if not, just try to express two of the variables $x$, $y$, $z$ in terms of the third. The first equation is almost useless: It only serves to ensure that the two given vectors are linearly independent – if they are non-zero, which I hope is a given.

Comment: I understand that the solution isn't unique. There's no doubt regarding that. And regarding that term, it doesn't ring a bell as I've, although done a lot of problems in vector algebra (not calculus - I don't know the difference), I've never seen this formula before. And as far as expressing two variables in terms of third is concerned, I am not able to do that. As I said, I am able to eliminate only one variable. That's where I need some help.

Comment: You are not familiar with the cross product? That would have helped, but it's not essential. You wrote that you have derived two more equations involving two variables each, for a total of three. You only need two of them, since the third will be a combination of the other two. The two equations you choose will have one variable in common. So use the two equations to express the *other* two variables in terms of that one, and you're basically done!

Comment: CROSS PRODUCT?! Oh I do know that! But that over here? Aaah! Now it all makes sense. Should've thought of that.